# What is this font effect called?

Tags: adobe-photoshop, fonts, photoshop-effects

The title says it all. What is the effect used in this image and how are there any good tutorials to do it in Photoshop?

[image]

Comment: The title really doesn't say it all. Could you not provide some description in the question to help differentiate from the many other similar questions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, you will need to download a Photoshop texture that will work for the line pattern. A quick search reveals this: http://www.shapes4free.com/vector-photoshop-patterns/80-simple-line-pixel-patterns/
several of which would work fine for what you need. The file will need to be unzipped once it is downloaded.

1. Type out the text that you want in its own layer, and then duplicate the layer.
2. Select the bottom text layer and use the move tool to move it to the desired location of the pattern effect. *(Holding down the shift key will snap the direction of movement to a 45-degree angle.)*
3. Making sure that the bottom text layer is selected, click the "fx" icon in the bottom of the layers panel, and select "pattern overlay".
4. Open the drop-down list of patterns, click on the small arrow on the right, and select "load patterns". Then, find the patterns that you downloaded and load them. *(Once the patterns are loaded, you may need to "append" them to your patterns pallet. Just click the small arrow again, select the pattern group that you want, and click "append").*
5. Click on the pattern that you want from the drop-down list, and then adjust the settings of the pattern overlay to taste.

Comment: With only two layers of text, you will get the not-so-desired jaggy effect. To get the proper line (bottom of T for example) you first need 5-10 layers of text, 1px by 1px off the previous one (yo can do this by a two-stroke copy-move, ALT+ARROW_LEFT then ARROW_UP). After that, merge all but first layers and apply pattern.

Comment: Or, you could just convert the pattern text layer to a shape layer, use the same pattern overlay, and adjust the points to suit the text angle.

Answer (score 2):

It's just called 3D type, as far as I'm aware. It was common in the late 19th century and very early 20th. If you wanted to look up further examples for inspiration, a search for `3D (woodcut|wood) type` would be a good starting place*.

Not sure how you'd do it in Pshop. Illustrator has some good tools for this. You could play with the 3D extrude and bevel settings to get you started. For the particular shading pattern here I think it would take a few steps.

**This would be my first shot in Illustrator:**

1. Apply 3D extrude and bevel to cast the basic "shadow" the way you want it.
2. Expand your finished effect to get to the actual vectors
3. Combine the shadows as necessary to make unified shapes
4. Fill the shadows with a horizontal stripe pattern built to match the angle of your shadows.
5. Apply a white stroke to the type for the slight separation (which you could then expand and subtract from the shadow area if you need it transparent)

* Okay, maybe that search wasn't so good afterall. Google doesn't seem to like old type samples. Thank goodness for BibliOdessey: **[here's a great post](http://bibliodyssey.blogspot.com/2012/06/county-map-title-page-letterforms.html) full of 18th Century 3D type.**

Comment: “Illustrator has some good tools for this” +1 on using Illustrator for this. Photoshop can definitely do it, but it'd be far easier to create the shapes in Illustrator, even if you end up texturing and colouring in Photoshop.